# Adding new directory to the $PATH

Tags: osx-lion, zsh, ringojs

In order to run new web application using `ringojs`, it's recommended to add the `ringojs` bin directory to your PATH environment variable, so i tried like so:

```
 echo 'export PATH=Users/repos/ringojs/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.profile
```

Then close and reopen the terminal, and tried to create new `ringojs` web app as described in the ringo [README](https://github.com/ringo/ringojs).

```
ringo-admin create --google-appengine myapp
```

However, i got always:

```
zsh: command not found: ringo-admin
```

Please note i have set the `ant` and `ivy` tools successfully. Am i missing something there? is the way to add to the `$PATH` incorrect?

**Update:**

After using Abraham suggestion, here is the .bash_profile content so far:

```
 <echo message=" test       --> run JUnit and RingoJS tests"/>
        <echo message=" docs       --> generates the API docs"/>
        <echo message=" package    --> creates RingoJS distribution"/>
        <echo message=" dpkg       --> creates RingoJS debian package"/>
        <echo message=" clean      --> clean up compiled resources"/>
    </target>

    <!-- =================================================================== -->
    <!-- Initializes some variables                                          -->
    <!-- =================================================================== -->
    <target name="init">
        <property name="project" value="ringojs"/>
        <property name="version" value="0.9"/>

        <property name="home" value="."/>

        <property name="src" value="${home}/src"/>
        <property name="lib" value="${home}/lib"/>
        <property name="build" value="${home}/build"/>
        <property name="classes" value="${build}/classes"/>
        <property name="docs" value="${home}/docs"/>
        <property name="jsdocs" value="${home}/docs/modules"/>
        <property name="javadocs" value="${home}/docs/java"/>

        <property name="ringo-core.jar" value="${lib}/ringo-core.jar"/>
        <property name="ringo-modules.jar" value="${lib}/ringo-modules.jar"/>

        <property name="debug" value="on"/>
        <property name="optimize" value="on"/>
        <property name="deprecation" value="on"/>

        <property name="testclasses" value=""/>

        <path id="classpath">
            <fileset dir="lib">
                <include name="**/*.jar"/>
                <exclude name="${ringo-core.jar}"/>
            </fileset>
            <pathelement location="${classes}"/>export PATH=Users/repos/ringojs/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.profile
```

However, i still get the same ringo-admin command not found, even though i closed and reopened the terminal session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.profile` file is sourced only if bash or other POSIX-compatible shell is a login shell. Zsh will source this only if it is invoked using symlink named `sh` (i.e. in POSIX compatibility mode). `.bash_profile` is the same, but only for bash. What you need is either adding this line to `.zshrc` (if you want to use this only in interactive sessions, should be preferred), `.zshenv` (for all sessions) or (the best if works) just try full system restart with new (with `export …` line) `.zprofile`: if there happens to be a login shell launched before normal one, it will work perfectly.

Note that if you choose to use `.zshrc` and, especially, `.zshenv` then you must check that new path is not already there: exported variables are passed to each parent process thus you will easily end up with a sequence of identical directories in `$PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are not initializing the PATH when you start a new terminal, rather you are setting it in only your current session.

What you want to do is type the following commands:

```
   cd ~
```

That will navigate to your home directory

```
   ls -al
```

List all files including hidden files. In the list that appears, verify that a file called .zprofile exists.

To create or edit the file, run

```
   vi .zprofile
```

to open the file. To move to the end of its contents, hit <kbd>Shift-G</kbd>, then (lowercase) <kbd>O</kbd> to add a new line and enter insert mode. Now type:

```
  export PATH=/Users/repos/ringojs/bin:$PATH
```

at the end of the file.

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, type `:x`, and press <kbd>Return</kbd>

Comment: Thanx for your reply. I tried it but i always got the ringo-admin command not found in the terminal, please take a look on my updated .bash_profile file above to check it if it's missing something. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Have you restarted your terminal since you've changed your .bash_profile?

Also, are you sure the file you posted above is your bash_profile? It looks nothing like a bash profile, nor does it include a PATH export

Comment: Good spot ZyX. Question revised for zh

Comment: You don’t need `touch`. If opened file does not exist, Vim will create it on save.